# Is there a solution to deploy a .net core application on IIS server without having to publish each time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I am having problems to deploy my .NET CORE 3.0 application on IIS 10.0, where I want to deploy it on the repository where there's the web.config (I used to do that with ASP.NET MVC and it used to work).
Is it possible to make it work ? if not what are the fastest ways to depoloy the application and check it just after building.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore"
           path="*"
           verb="*"
           modules="AspNetCoreModule"
           resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
                arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
                stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Impossible is the answer.

Comment: According to your description, I still couldn't understand your requirement. What you mean about check it? Debug the application or check the generated file?

Comment: @LexLi can you tell me why please ?

Comment: It is designed that way where `dotnet publish` is a mandate step, whether you like it or not.